# Rails4: SMTPAuthenticationError when sending Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, gmail

Although I tried to add "Forgotten Password" functionality by reference to RAILSCAST #247, the error message "We're sorry, but something went wrong." was displayed on browser in production environment(not Heroku).

The same error happened after accessing the links below.
http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

The stdout.log is the following;

```
Started POST "/password_resets" for 12.345.67.89 at 2014-12-27 09:10:24 +0000
Processing by PasswordResetsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "email"=>"xxx@xxx.com", "commit"=>"reset PW"}
  Rendered user_mailer/password_reset.text.erb (1.1ms)

Sent mail to xxx@xxx.com (1617.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1775ms

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=xxx
):
  app/models/user.rb:36:in `send_password_reset'
  app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

The contents of these files which caused errors are as below.

\app\models\user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!(validate: false)
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver    #line 36
  end
.
.
```

\app\controllers\password_resets_controller.rb

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
.
.
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user          #line 6
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email sent with password reset instructions."
  end
.
.
```

I added some settings in production.rb to use Gmail by reference to RailsGuides.

\config\environments\production.rb

```
.
.
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' } #change to hosting setting
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'example.com', #change to hosting setting
  :user_name            => 'xxx@gmail.com',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
.
.
```

Please advise me on how to avoid this error.

Comment: google mail prevent smtp auth by default, try find in setting gmail account something about this.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, @Зелёны. It works as it is. It seemed that it took a long time to refrect `UnlockCaptcha` or `lesssecureapps`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a gmail account (ending in gmail.com), the `domain` portion of `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` should be changed as follows:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'gmail.com',
  :user_name            => 'xxx@gmail.com',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

You'd only need to set `domain` to example.com if you were using a google apps account with the  example.com domain.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, @sjaime. It works though I don't try your answer. It seemed that it took a long time to refrect `UnlockCaptcha` or `lesssecureapps`.